# Linear independence in isomorphic vector spaces

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a linear transformation
where $n\geq2$. For $k\leq n$, let 
$$E=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},\dots,v_{k}\}\mbox{ and } F=\{Tv_{1},Tv_{2},\dots,Tv_{k}\}.$$

then

(A)  $E$ is L.I$\Longrightarrow F$ is L.I

(B)  $F$ is L.I$\Longrightarrow E$ is L.I

(C)  $E$ is L.I$\Longrightarrow F$ is L.D

(D)  $F$ is L.I$\Longrightarrow E$ is L.D
[L.I = linear independent,L.D= linear dependent

MY APPROACH= one book says C is correct another says D is correct.But i think A and B both are correct because T is linear operator

Comment: To show that A is not correct, consider the linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ taking every vector to $0$, i.e. $T(v)=0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. C and D are both incorrect if you take $T$ as the identity map. B is the only correct one.

Comment: Note that for the particular case in which $T$ is injective, (A) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** If $F$ is linearly independent then $E$ is linearly independent.

**Solution:** Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_1v_i=0$ for some constant $c_i \in \mathbb R$,now apply $T$ both side and use the fact that $T(0)=0$ and $F$ is linearly independent...

Comment: And the converse???

Comment: Did you read the comment by Levent?